# How to calculate probability of additional components succeeding

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If I have three components each succeeding with probabilities `P1, P2, P3`, (and failing with `1-P1, 1-P2 and 1-P3`) how can I calculate the probability of just 1 additional component succeeding?

Something like `(P1 U P2 U P3) - P(more than 1 succeeding)` is there a way to generalize this?

So for example, the probability of 0 components succeeding is:

```
P(0 succeed) = (1-P1)*(1-P2)*(1-P3)
```

I was hoping to chain things using something like:

```
P(1 success) = P(1 success | 0 success) * P(0 succees)
P(2 success) = P(2 success | 1 success) * P(1 success)
P(3 success) = P(3 success | 2 success) * P(2 success)
```

but that doesn't seem to yield an easy calculation at all.

Comment: For finding probability of exactly one success just do `P1(1-P2)(1-P3)+(1-P1)P2(1-P3)+(1-P1)(1-P2)P3`.  Yes, that will get ugly for larger sets of components, but without some sort of symmetry there is not much better you can do.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to find that symmetry/pattern, not yet finding it, but I bet it's there somewhere. The binomial distribution works for P1=P2=P3.

Comment: Moving to four components to make the pattern clearler, if you insist you can write it as `P1(1-P2)(1-P3)(1-P4)+(1-P1)(P2(1-P3)(1-P4)+(1-P2)(P3(1-P4)+(1-P3)P4))` and save a little bit in terms of operations.  That does not feel simpler to read... but it may be simpler to program and more efficient in terms of performance speed.  That way `P1` only appears in the calculation twice, `P2` appears three times, and so on... rather than everything appearing `n` times.

Comment: Is the probability of each component succeeding *independent* of the probability of any of the other components succeeding?

Comment: @user2661923 yes independent